# Are there adaptors available letting to connect a USB device to a BlueTooth host?

Tags: usb, bluetooth

There are many USB-attached BlueTooth host controllers letting a user to attach a BlueTooth device to a computer having USB ports but no integrated BlueTooth support. Does an opposite thing exist? A way to connect a conventional wired USB device to a computer having integrated BlueTooth host controller but no USB ports?

Answer (score 4):

In short, its been in progress for a while, and has more or less died.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_USB

Answer (score 3):

Not yet.  Still in development.